# Proxy for abstract class without changing the usage

Tags: java, oop, aop, aspectj

I have an abstract class (database mapping) implementing an interface where default implementations are injected at runtime (this is part of another library and cannot be changed).

I want to override one of the default implementation via a proxy (as that seems like the way to override this).

```
public abstract class Table1 implements Storable<Table1>
{   
    @Sequence("ID_SEQUENCE")
    @Alias("ID")
    public abstract String getID();
    public abstract void setID(String ID);

    @Alias("NAME")
    public abstract String getAvailabilityZone();
    public abstract void setAvailabilityZone(String value);
}

public interface Storable<S extends Storable<S>> {
     //a bunch of method definition.
     boolean tryLoad() throws Exception;
}
```

Let's say I want to override tryLoad() method to do my own things instead of what the generated code provides. Given the nature of the library, it is not something I can achieve by simple @Override.
The simple way this is currently used is as following:

```
public void method() {
        Table1 t = Repository.storageFor(Table1.class).prepare();
        t.setName( "temp" );
        if (!t.tryLoad())
           t.tryInsert();
}
```

I want to proxy tryLoad() without making changes in all the methods across the whole codebase - that would be to get proxied instance instead of actual one and perform the operation on that.

Is there any recommended way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a new class that implements the interface. Make this class store the injected implemention as a private variable... and use this variable for all other methods of the interface except for the one you wanna override

Comment: Is the library a secret? Please name it so I can take a look at it. Can you elaborate on the following statement so I can tell you if and how you can solve this via AspectJ which by the way does not use any dynamic proxies (Spring AOP does, but the latter is only an "AOP lite" solution, AspectJ a full-blown one). You said: _"I want to override tryLoad() method to do my own things instead of what the generated code provides. Given the nature of the library, it is not something I can achieve by simple @Override."_ Why is that? What stops you from overriding? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: http://carbonado.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/amazon/carbonado/Storable.html#tryLoad() this is what I want to override but it is implemented via runtime code injection for optimization -  https://github.com/Carbonado/Carbonado/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/carbonado/gen/StorableGenerator.java#L100

Comment: As you can see, these methods are written with a wrapper over the assembly and injected at the runtime. A simple override will not invoke this as it is. Let me know if you have any other questions.

I can achieve it via Proxy but I want to do it without making the changes to the client to create a proxy object for every Storable object.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed your comments or was not notified, whatever. Can you please provide a tiny [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on GitHub, ideally a Maven build, maybe with an in-memory DB? Something I can just clone and run. I do not know that library, so it would help me understand your problem and help you solve it.

Comment: Please also explain where the references `storage` and `az` come from in your sample method. If I understand correctly, `method()` is what your override should look like. Is this what the aspect or proxy should execute whenever the original `tryLoad()` method is executed? And am I correct that `az.tryLoad()` calls the original method and thus your override delegates back to the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woke up last night and felt bored, so despite your lack of feedback I created a little [Carbonado showcase project](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_CarbonadoOverride) and shared it on GitHub. I made three commits:

1. [Initial commit](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_CarbonadoOverride/commit/8707853eaa09d911f4fb8011b2f8f6aa8958fdfa) with Maven project already prepared for AspectJ and a JUnit test for me to find out how Carbonado actually works, because I had never used it before.
2. [Add failing unit test](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_CarbonadoOverride/commit/da73f03d692de5a36dcae5def34a5077eb852cf9) for behaviour of `tryLoad()` expected to be provided by aspect.
3. [Add aspect to make unit test pass](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_CarbonadoOverride/commit/9c8f8009aa155cebb888df443eb8411d7a22f2a8). Aspect hooks into `tryLoad()` and auto-creates non-existent record. I do not know if I guessed right what you actually wanted to achieve, but if it was a different thing, just change the aspect implementation.

#### Sample code

**Carbonado storable:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import com.amazon.carbonado.Nullable;
import com.amazon.carbonado.PrimaryKey;
import com.amazon.carbonado.Storable;

@PrimaryKey("ID")
public interface StoredMessage extends Storable<StoredMessage> {
  long getID();
  void setID(long id);
  @Nullable String getMessage();
  void setMessage(String message);
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import com.amazon.carbonado.Storable;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class CarbonadoAspect {
  @Around("call(boolean tryLoad()) && target(storable)")
  public boolean tryInsertIfNotFound(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Storable storable) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    if ((boolean) thisJoinPoint.proceed())
      return true;
    System.out.println("Not found: " + storable + " -> inserting");
    return storable.tryInsert();
  }
}
```

**JUnit test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.amazon.carbonado.FetchException;
import com.amazon.carbonado.PersistException;
import com.amazon.carbonado.Repository;
import com.amazon.carbonado.RepositoryException;
import com.amazon.carbonado.Storage;
import com.amazon.carbonado.SupportException;
import com.amazon.carbonado.repo.map.MapRepositoryBuilder;

import de.scrum_master.app.StoredMessage;

public class CarbonadoTest {
  private Repository repo;
  private Storage<StoredMessage> storage;
  StoredMessage message;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    repo = MapRepositoryBuilder.newRepository();
    storage = repo.storageFor(StoredMessage.class);
    message = storage.prepare();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    repo.close();
    repo = null;
    storage = null;
    message = null;
  }

  // (...)

  @Test
  public void aspectCreatesNonExistentRecord() throws SupportException, RepositoryException {
    message.setID(1);
    // Without the aspect this would be false
    assertTrue(message.tryLoad());
    assertEquals(message.getID(), 1);
    assertEquals(message.getMessage(), null);
  }

}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @kriegaex. I got busy with some other things and missed this completely. This is exactly what will make it work. I think the problem I was misunderstanding was related to the fact that generated methods will work fine with the AspectJ. Thanks again!